# How to apply filter to Python script to download specific email attachment

Tags: python

Good morning,

I am trying to add a filter to only download the csv attachment from an email, not the pdf.
The below script works, but its downloading both attachments.

Thank you

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import email
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


outlook = 
win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("GCAM")
message = inbox.items



for message in inbox.Items:
if message.unread == True:
    attachments = message.Attachments
    Attachments = attachments.Item(2)
    for attachment in message.Attachments:

        print(attachment.FileName)enter code here
```

Comment: You are expected to add your code, and data as text that can be copied, please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: same comment as @ThePyGuy, add your code as text, the image doesn't help too much.

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice. I have amended the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but this should work:

```
import win32com.client
import datetime
import os
import email
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob


outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders("GCAM")

for message in inbox.Items:
    if message.unread == True:
        attachments = message.Attachments
        Attachments = attachments.Item(2)
        for attachment in message.Attachments:
            if attachment.FileName.split(".")[-1] == "csv":
                print(attachment.FileName)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I knew I needed an IF argument somewhere, but you've clarified it. I really appreciate your help.